# regex explode url parts

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url

```
// repeat /?([^/)? 10 times
preg_match("`/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?/?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?`");
```

This is the regex that I use to parse request uri without query. It can capture up to 10 url parts. That's not optimal nor good. Current workaround is to put more than enough `/?([^/]+)` and hope that no one will exceed that limit.

Is there a regex that can capture unlimited url parts? Basically I need regex that does this: `explode('/', $url)`.

**Caveat: Can use only preg_match!**

No explode, preg_match_all, g,

Comment: What about `(/?([^/]+))*`?

Comment: what about `parse_str`?

Comment: Just curious, why cant you use explode?

Comment: @Tom Hart: Whole url router uses preg_match and that's it. I can use "`.`" for last check and than in closure explode request_uri. I was hoping there is pure/clean regex solution.

Comment: @marsze Doesn't seem to work https://www.regex101.com/r/lZ0jV4/2

Comment: @u_mulder _parse_str() uses the same mechanism that PHP uses to populate the $_GET, $_POST_ I don't need url query, I need path parts from url.

Comment: I think exploding the path in the closure is a clean solution.

Comment: @rici No problem. I'll use that. I just wanted to be sure that I am not missing some arcane regex solution.

Comment: @CoR: Suppose you could expand a repeated capture into multiple captures. What number would the *following* capture have? If you couldn't figure that out, the regex capture mechanism would be flawed. (Of course, numbering captures is a flawed interface, but it's cheap and traditional.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you shown the router compenent you are using: `Seriously Simple Router`.

The solution is to access that sort of information in the controller, not in the router. Following example shows how you can do it:

```
// Wrap the whole url into the first capturing group to
// forward it to the controller
Router::route('(a/b/c/([\d]+))', function($url, $id) {
  var_dump(explode('/', $url));
});

Router::execute($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: Why? `$parse_url['path'] === $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - optional query`

Comment: can you use preg_match_all?

Comment: @ hek2mgl _No explode, preg_match_all, g,_ I have only preg_match on my disposal

Comment: Then there is no chance. Did you wrote the router on your own?

Comment: Impossible is good answer. There are couple of workarounds. I thought I was missing some simple regex arcane solution. And no, it's mod of [seriously simple router](http://upshots.org/php/php-seriously-simple-router)

Comment: Why do you want to capture those url parts in spearate matching groups?

Comment: Because as last check I need each url part to be array[p1, p2, ..., pn] like explode does. Which I have as workaround no.2! I thought it could be done with regex. I love clean solutions. But if it's not possible, it's ok. Ill use workaround no1 or no2. Change your answer to impossible under this conditions so I can accept it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71687/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-cor).